# How to generate grouped bar plot or pie chart from list of csv files?

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

I got list of data.frame that need to be classified, I did manipulate these list and finally export them as csv files in default folder. However, to make these exported data more informative, I think it is better to generate grouped bar plot, or pie chart for each data.frame objects. As a beginner, I am still learning features of ggplot2 packages, so I have little idea how to do this easily. Can any one give me possible ideas how to generate grouped bar plot easily ? How can I generate well informative bar plot for list of files ? How can I make this happen ? Any idea ? Thanks in advance :)

reproducible data :

```
savedDF <- list(
  bar.saved = data.frame(start=sample(100, 15), stop=sample(150, 15), score=sample(36, 15)),
  cat.saved = data.frame(start=sample(100, 20), stop=sample(100,20), score=sample(45,20)),
  foo.saved = data.frame(start=sample(125, 24), stop=sample(140, 24), score=sample(32, 24))
)

dropedDF <- list(
  bar.droped = data.frame(start=sample(60, 12), stop=sample(90,12), score=sample(35,12)),
  cat.droped = data.frame(start=sample(75, 18), stop=sample(84,18), score=sample(28,18)),
  foo.droped = data.frame(start=sample(54, 14), stop=sample(72,14), score=sample(25,14))
)
```

so I am getting list of csv files from this pipeline :

```
comb <- do.call("rbind", c(savedDF, dropedDF))
cn <- c("letter", "saved","seq")
DF <- cbind(read.table(text = chartr("_", ".", rownames(comb)), sep = ".", col.names = cn), comb)
DF <- transform(DF, updown = ifelse(score>= 12, "stringent", "weak"))
by(DF, DF[c("letter", "saved", "updown")], 
   function(x) write.csv(x[-(1:3)], 
                         sprintf("%s_%s_%s.csv", x$letter[1], x$updown[1], x$saved[1])))
```

To better understand the exported data, I think generating grouped bar plot and pie chart for each data.frame object will be much informative.

In desired plot, I intend to see number of features in each csv files for each data.frame objects. Can any one give me ideas to do this task ?

How can I make this happen easily by using ggplot2 packages ? Is there any way to get this done more efficiently ? Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you want the bar plot to look like?  For instance, your `DF` has several variables which do you want to illustrate in the bar ? (e.g. x = seq, y = score)

Comment: Number of features, as in the number of variables?

Comment: @Jerry.Shad rows are typically observations, not variables.

Comment: @Axeman sorry, you are right. y label represent number of observations.

Comment: @JakeKaupp x = name of csv files, y = number of observation in csv files

Comment: @JakeKaupp how can I get pie chart for these csv files ? Is that possible to change the layout to make it nicer ? Thank you :)

Comment: Yes it is possible to change the layout, and you should investigate `ggplot2` to figure out how to do this on your own.  The documentation is quite clear and there are lots of examples here on SO.

Comment: To clarify, you want a pie chart for the file bar, illustrated the 4 combinations by updown and saved as the pie pieces? (e.g. stringent_dropped, stringent_saved, weak_dropped, weak_saved)

Comment: @JakeKaupp based on mock up example, is possible to get desired plot accordingly ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Those can all be done using the packages in my solutions below.  You are using permutations of `geom_bar()` in `ggplot2`.  Prior to that you just need to filter your data to what you need.  If you need a report with all the images above you are best looking into the `gridExtra` package to combine all the plots.   There are several examples on SO on how to achieve this. Your first step should be to make all the individual plots you need then figure out how to arrange them.

Comment: @JakeKaupp as a beginner, could you enlighten me how to make it in desired way ? which changes will be needed in your solution ? Is that possible to update your solution ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I've shown how to make the plots, this will show you how to arrange them :https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html if you run into problems search SO, if you can't find a solution, make a new question!

Comment: @JakeKaupp Thank you. I'll practice your solution, it is cool :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this may work for you as a rough solution.  Please comment to let me know if this is acceptable.  In the future, if you can provide a rough sketch along with your data to show what you're trying to achieve that would be a good idea.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

plot_data <- DF %>% 
  group_by(letter, saved, updown) %>% 
  tally %>% 
  group_by(saved, updown) %>% 
  mutate(percentage = n/sum(n))

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = saved, y = n, fill = saved)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ letter + updown, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

You can always change the `facet_wrap(~ letter + updown, ncol = 2)` to an explicit `facet_grid(letter ~ updown)` if you wish.

Or you could view it this way:

```
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = letter, y = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~updown+saved, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

For a pie (cleaning up and labeling is up to you):

```
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = 1, y = percentage, fill = letter)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width =1) +
  facet_wrap(~updown+saved, ncol = 2) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

The bar, 4 interaction pie just requires some manipulating of your data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

plot_data <- DF %>% 
  unite(interaction, saved, updown, sep = "-") %>% 
  group_by(letter, interaction) %>% 
  tally %>% 
  mutate(percentage = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  filter(letter == "bar")

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = 1, y = percentage, fill = interaction)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width =1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

You should really look into `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `ggplot2` packages. Read their documentation and vignettes and work through the exmaples.  Best way to learn is by doing.

Comment: Could I get pie chart as well ? Thank you :)

Comment: This is really cool. I definitely follow up your recommendation. Thanks a lot ;)